# como busco por fechas en mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.get('/tactividades/:pagina', (req,res) => {
    let porpagina = 5
    let pagina = req.params.pagina || 1

    Actividad.
    find({})
    .skip((porpagina*pagina)-porpagina)
    .limit(porpagina)
    .exec((err,act) => {
       Actividad.countDocuments((err,cuenta) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }
            res.render('tactividades',{
                act:act,
                actual:pagina,
                base: req.baseUrl,
                paginas: Math.ceil(cuenta/porpagina)
            })
        })

    })
})
```

buenas tardes amigos necesito su ayuda con respecto a una busqueda por fechas, esa ruta me funciona bien incluso la paginacion pero quisiera agregar otra ruta como la que mostrare abajo para que me busque por una fecha la cual estoy enviando a traves de un campo date desde html y me envia bien en formato yyyy-m-d la cuestion es que no se como buscar en mongoose y despues mostrarlo de manera que me retorne la pagina donde esta ese dia o no se si sea mas facil mostrarlo en otra vista solo esa de busqueda, de la manera que sea mas sencilla

router.get('/buscar', (req,res) => {

```
    Actividad.findOne({fecha:ISODate("2014-10-19T16:36:14.197Z") })
    .exec((err,act)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log('hubo un error')
        }
        console.log(act)
    })   
    console.log('este es lo q se envia'+ req.body.fecha)
    res.redirect('tactividades')
})
```

en esta parte estoy tirando flechas jajaja , no se como hacer busqueda con mongoose, desde mongodb se usa Isodate('') en la comparacion pero para mongoose es invalido. que metodo y como sugieren que haga esa busqueda especifica de un dia de reporte especifico? saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: muchas gracias amigo si me ha ayudado tu aporte pero me de dado cuenta que el comando eq se usa para igualdades y esta bien pero el usarlo ahora me lleva a otro dilema, que generalmente cuando se guarda una fecha tambien se guarda la hora de esta manera en mongoose 2019-03-28T03:04:55.000Z entonces como yo uso el input date que tiene el calendario, los parametros que envio por post solo me genera año mes y dia lo cual es correcto y es lo que quiero el detalle es que cuando quiero comparar no quiero comparar horas, cual seria la manera mas optima que me recomiendas para lograr el cometido ? gra

Comment: Puedes revisar la edición que hice en la respuesta para que logres realizar lo que te propones. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar una búsqueda por fecha usando Mongoose debes usar un operador de comparación en tu `query`. Para este caso el operador será `$eq`.

Puedes realizar la comparación directamente dentro del método `findOne` o puedes crear un constructor para el objeto `query` al cual le aplicas luego el filtro de comparación usando la cláusula `where`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una búsqueda por fecha en una colección de MongoDB usando Mongoose.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Puedes realizar la consulta de dos formas, la primera es la más directa, colocando el operador de comparación directamente dentro del método `findOne()` del modelo sobre el que realizas la consulta. Antes de realizar la consulta, debes construir un objeto `Date` de Javascript y es este objeto el que pasarás como argumento para la comparación, o puedes crear directamente el objeto en tu campo de búsqueda.

```
const fechaBusqueda = new Date('2014-10-19T16:36:14.197Z');
Actividad.findOne({fecha: {$eq: fechaBusqueda}})
    .exec((err, act) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('hubo un error');
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.message}); //debes enviar una respuesta o llamar al manejador de errores (return next(err))
        }
        console.log(act);
        return res.status(200).json(act); // en este ejemplo se envía el resultado
    });
});
```

En caso de que quieras usar un constructor para el objeto `query` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Actividad
    .findOne({})
    .where({fecha: {$eq: new Date('2014-10-19T16:36:14.197Z')}})
    .exec((err, act) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('hubo un error');
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.message}); //debes enviar una respuesta o llamar al manejador de errores (return next(err))
        }
        console.log(act);
        return res.status(200).json(act); // en este ejemplo se envía el resultado
    });
});
```

Con esto ya tienes dos maneras de realizar la tarea.

Puedes consultar [aquí](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) más información sobre el operador de comparación $eq en MongoDB.

También puedes consultar [aquí](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) más información sobre el objeto `query` de Mongoose.

**Nota**

Te preguntarás porqué no uso el tipo de dato [`ISODate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/) de MongoDB. La razón es que ese tipo de dato es efectivamente de MongoDB. Específicamente del shell de MongoDB. Fue creado como un ***wrapper*** para el tipo `Date` de Javascript.

Además, estás trabajando con Mongoose. En Mongoose, los tipos de datos disponibles para trabajar con Esquemas (y por lo tanto con Modelos) incluyen a `Date` y no a `ISODate`. Es por eso que como parámetro de búsqueda pasamos un tipo `Date`.

Espero que esto haya respondido tu duda.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que planteas en tu comentario que la fecha la obtienes desde un `input` tipo `date`, que generan una cadena con el formato "YYYY/MM/DD", entonces debes hacer un par de cosas antes de enviar la consulta.

En primer lugar debo recordarte que las fechas en MongoDB se guardan en formato `ISODate`, esto quiere decir que se guardan con zona horaria neutra o lo que es lo mismo `GMT 0`, independientemente de la zona horaria del cliente que realiza las operaciones en la BD. Así por ejemplo, yo estoy en la zona horaria GMT+1:00:00, por lo tanto una fecha `Date` generada en mi equipo digamos: `new Date()` a las "22:23" horas se almacenará en la base de datos como: `ISODate("2019-03-28T21:23:07.095Z")`, es decir, le restará 1 hora correspondiente a mi zona horaria.

Dicho esto, lo que vamos a hacer es construir dos objetos tipo `Date` usando como parámetro la cadena recibida en la solicitud. Esto indicará nuestra fecha de búsqueda inicial y final.

```
// suponiendo que req.body.fechaBusqueda contiene '2019/03/26'
const fechaInicial = req.body.fechaBusqueda;
const fechaFinal = fechaInicial.substring(0,8).concat(Number(fechaInicial.substring(8)) + 1);
```

Analicemos `fechaFinal`: la primera parte es clara, estamos haciendo un `substring(0,8)` que nos trae: `'2019/03/'`, ahora le vamos a concatenar el valor de '26 + 1', es decir le concatenaremos '27', esto es para indicar que nuestro rango de búsqueda es de 1 día.

Recordemos que si creamos un objeto tipo `Date` en Javascript y le pasamos como parámetro una cadena con formato "YYYY/MM/DD", la hora asignada a dicho objeto será "00:00:00:000" en la zona horaria en la que nos encontremos. Asi que nuestras fecha inicial y final tienen una diferencia exacta de 24 horas.

Ya con esto podemos hacer la búsqueda en la BD, pero esta vez usaremos el método `find()`, ya que tal vez exista más de una actividad en el rango de fechas que estamos usando.

La consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Actividad.find({$and: [{fecha: {$gte: new Date(fechaInicial)}},{fecha: {$lt: new Date(fechaFinal)}}]}, ...);
```

Analicemos esto:

**$and: []**: es un operador para indicar que se verificará la validez de todos los `query` que se pasan en el `array`.

**{fecha: {$gte: new Date(fechaInicial)}}**: el primer `query` que indica que buscamos documentos cuya fecha sea mayor o igual (**g**reater **t**han or **e**qual) a `fechaInicial`.

**{fecha: {$lt: new Date(fechaFinal)}}**: el segundo `query` que indica que buscamos documentos cuya fecha sea menor (**l**ess **t**han) que `fechaFinal`.

Por último una posible implementación de la ruta puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
app.post('/api/actividad/bydate', (req, res, next) => {
    const fechaInicial = req.body.fechaBusqueda; // ejemplo: '2019/03/26'
    const fechaFinal = fechaInicial.substring(0,8).concat(Number(fechaInicial.substring(8)) + 1);

    Actividad.find({$and: [{fecha: {$gte: new Date(fechaInicial)}},{fecha: {$lt: new Date(fechaFinal)}}]}, (err, actividad) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err.message
            });
        }
        if(!actividad) {  // si no se consiguen documentos
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'No se ha encontrado actividad en la fecha dada.'
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).json(actividad);
    });
});
```

Espero que esto responda tu nueva inquietud.

**NOTA**

Como no especificas el formato devuelto por el elemento `input`, yo he asumido que es "YYYY/MM/DD", si fuese otro, debes ajustar el uso del método `substring` e incluso la forma en que construyes el objeto `Date`.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda mauricio, plantie y entendi tal cual me sugeriste para solucionar pero no me esta funcionando bien el filtro en el sentido que me esta trayendo todos los documentos cuando hay una fecha que coincide lo cual no deberia, cuando no coincide trae vacio, esa parte esta correcta pero coloco una fecha 25 y me trae del 26 todos. aun analizo a ver como lo puedo arrglar jeje por otro lado e estado pensando probar resolver con expresion regular pasando a string la fecha

Comment: ¿Podrías subir la forma en que recibes el campo *fecha* de tu `input`? Me gustaría ver como has implementado la ruta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

> tenia todo igual a vos y la respuesta de Mauricio me dio el mismo error que a vos...

En vez de usar:

```
Actividad.find({$and: [{fecha: {$gte: new Date(fechaInicial)}},{fecha: {$lt: new Date(fechaFinal)}}]}, (err, actividad) => {
```

Lo cambié por:

```
Actividad.find({$and: [{fecha: {$gte: new Date(fechaInicial), $lt: new Date(fechaFinal)}}]}, (err, actividad) => {
```

Queda mas claro que el *and* condiciona a la misma fecha, incluyendo `$lt` dentro de la llave de condiciones!